# Comparing DOM elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am working inside of a jQuery `each` iterator:

`$('p').each(function(){ ... });`

I'd like to create an expression that evaluates to true when:

- `$(this)` is the last `p` element
- scope is `$(this).parent()`
- `$(this)` must be a direct child of `$(this).parent()`
- `$(this)` is not necessarily the last direct child of `$(this).parent()`

Here are a few scenarios, with the desired `p` marked by asterisks:

```
<div>
  <p>div1 p1</p>
  <p>div1 p2</p>
  <p>div1 p3***</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>div2 p1***</p>
  <span>div2 s1</span>
</div>

<div>
  <p>div3 p1***</p>
  <div>
    div3 d1
    <p>div3 p2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd post my attempts at a solution, but there have been too many failed ones. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a selector such as this:

```
$('body > div').each(function() {
    $(this).children('p:last').each(function() { /* ... */ });
});
```

which would return all your wanted `<p>` tags.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/orage | [See Source](http://jsbin.com/orage/edit)

---

Your original requirements does not make any sense.

> `$(this)` must be a direct child of `$(this).parent()`

`$(this)` is ALWAYS a direct child of `$(this).parent()` by definition of what `parent()` does.