# When do we compare DOM elements in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('body > div').each(function() {
...
});
```

What functionality does comparing `body > div` provide?

This is a part of answer provided to this question
[Comparing DOM elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231283/comparing-dom-elements-with-jquery)
.
I want to do similar thing but I am not able to understand the functionality provided by comparing two DOM objects.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "comparing `body > div`". Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a comparison. It's a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). What it does is this:

> Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements
>   specified by "parent".

So if you have HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <span>A span</span>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <span>A span</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Then `$("div > span")` will select the first `span`, because it's a child of a `div`, but it won't select the second, because that's a child of a `p`.

Note that removing the child selector, and using `$("div span")` will select *both* `span` elements, because that looks for `span` elements that are *descendants* of a `div`, not specifically *children*.

Answer (score 0):

The `>` CSS selector is not comparing, it is the child selector.

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)